# Auth with firebase. AuthWithOAuthPopup is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm following Wes Bos `react for beginner` tutorial (updated) and I'm stuck with authentication with firebase. Trying to authenticate with github.

Getting an error `TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__base__.a.AuthWithOAuthPopup is not a function`

My code seems to be the same as in the tutorial:

```
class Inventory extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.renderInventory = this.renderInventory.bind(this);
    this.renderLogin = this.renderLogin.bind(this);
    this.authenticate = this.authenticate.bind(this);
    this.authHandler = this.authHandler.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      uid: null,
      owner: null
    }
  }

  handleChange(e, key) {
    const fish = this.props.fishes[key];
    const updatedFish = {
      ...fish,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }
    this.props.updateFish(key, updatedFish);
  }

  authenticate(provider){
    console.log(`trying to login with ${provider}`);
    base.authWithOAuthPopup(provider, this.authHandler);
  }

  authHandler(err, authData) {
    console.log(authData);

  }
  renderLogin() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Log In</h1>
        <button onClick={() => this.authenticate('github')}>Log In with Email</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

This is how does my base.js file look like:

```
import Rebase from 're-base';
import firebase from 'firebase';

const config = {
   KEYS
};

const app = firebase.initializeApp(config)
const base = Rebase.createClass(app.database())

export default base;
```

Comment: How are you importing `base` ?

Comment: `import base from '../base';`

Comment: Can you share that file too ?

Comment: Just updated my post with base.js

Comment: Looks like `authWithOAuthPopup` is deprecated:  https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base#changes-to-authentication-methods

Comment: OK... What's the solution then...? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

authWithOAuthPopup is deprecated in the latest version of Rebase. You could use `signInWithEmailAndPassword` instead. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithEmailAndPassword

Comment: Thanks man, I have found this `Migration guide`. But don't know how to implement it and change from what I currently have. https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base/blob/master/docs/MIGRATION.md

Comment: See this issue also: https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base/issues/225